# In Android Marshmallow, How to turn-off the mock locations in Developer option?

Tags: android, location

I have enabled mock locations in my mobile which runs on Android 6.0 . Now I want to turn it off badly as I could not use few location based apps. I could not find any option with "Turn-off mock location". It just shows "Select mock location app" for which it shows "none" when selected. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can install **adb** (Android Debug Bridge) by following [these instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/) for the Windows operating system.

Once you have **adb** installed, and have confirmed your phone is connected and recognized by adb (as per the same instructions I linked), start a Windows command prompt (typing `cmd` at the Start Menu). At the command line, you will type `adb shell`.

At the next prompt, type `settings put secure mock_location 0`. This will programmatically turn off mock locations on your connected Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work anymore with the update to marshmallow. There is no option to turn it off. You can only select an app to which you would like to use for mock locations. You're going to have to undo your system update. That's the only solution I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

in developer options, where you select an app to which you would like to use for mock locations, there is also an option for "Nothing". Maybe this will disable mock locations.

Answer (score -2):

Go into settings - about phone. Find developer number and tap 7 times, this will allow developer mode. 
Go back to settings and a new menu called developer options will be accessible. Within that turn off mock locations.

Comment: You can tell OP already has developer settings on from the mention of select mock location app, yet your instructions are merely to turn on developer settings which is useless for the problem OP has described. The actual issue where mock locations cannot be turned off started occuring with the latest Marshmallow update.